# Flutter plugin GoogleMLKit -- malloc: *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug

Tags: ios, objective-c, flutter-plugin, google-mlkit

I am using the `GoogleMLKit` `MLKBarcodeScanner`.

It's used in an Flutter plugin in iOS and Objective-C.

```
malloc: Heap corruption detected, free list is damaged
alloc: *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
```

```
void Scanner::scanWithFireBaseML(UIImage uiImage, Code &dst) {

    MLKBarcodeScannerOptions *options = [[MLKBarcodeScannerOptions alloc] initWithFormats: MLKBarcodeFormatAll];

    MLKVisionImage *visionImage = [[MLKVisionImage alloc] initWithImage:uiImage];
    visionImage.orientation = uiImage.imageOrientation;

     MLKBarcodeScanner *barcodeScanner = [MLKBarcodeScanner barcodeScannerWithOptions:options];

    [barcodeScanner processImage:visionImage
                      completion:^(NSArray<MLKBarcode *> *_Nullable barcodes,
                                   NSError *_Nullable error) {
      if (error != nil) {
        // Error handling
        return;
      }
      if (barcodes.count > 0) {
          for (MLKBarcode *barcode in barcodes) {
              NSString *displayValue = barcode.displayValue;
              NSString *rawValue = barcode.rawValue;

              NSLog(@"displayValue: ");
              NSLog(displayValue);
              NSLog(@"rawValue: ");
              NSLog(rawValue);

              //NSStiring to std::string
              std::string value = std::string([displayValue UTF8String]);
              dst.value =  value;
          }
      }
   }];
}
```

The App crashes when detecting a valid Code. While debugging I can see, that the code was read correctly but after finishing, the app crashes with the output above.

The variable error is always nil.

Comment: Is ```dst.value``` ok? Show it's definition ... also ```dst``` is passed by address so easily something can go wrong there.

Comment: No there is something going on with dst.My bad.
Thank you!